# snmpwalk not seeing mibs

Tags: ubuntu, snmp, net-snmp

Having a strange problem using Ubuntu 15.10. Yesterday I had to do a reboot due to a system update, and after the reboot 2 of the MIBs I use - LM-SENSORS-MIB and UCD-DISKIO-MIB do not work in snmpwalk. I can still find the OID with snmptranslate, and it's installed in /usr/share/snmp/mibs.

```
snmptranslate -IR -On LM-SENSORS-MIB::lmTempSensorsValue.6
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.13.16.2.1.3.6
```

^ works to find the OID, but below does not find anything except what I typed:

```
snmpwalk localhost . | grep lmTemp
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunParameters.28399 = STRING: "--color=auto lmTemp"
```

It's not seeing the OID either:

```
snmpwalk localhost . | grep 2021.13.16.2.1.3.6
```

Verified it's installed:

```
ls /usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM*
/usr/share/snmp/mibs/LM-SENSORS-MIB.txt
```

Contents of /etc/default/snmp:

```
cat /etc/default/snmpd
# This file controls the activity of snmpd

# Don't load any MIBs by default.
# You might comment this lines once you have the MIBs downloaded.
#export MIBS=

# snmpd control (yes means start daemon).
SNMPDRUN=yes

# snmpd options (use syslog, close stdin/out/err).
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u root -g 0 -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid'
```

Note - I do have mibs +ALL in the /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I couldn't list anything for LM-SENSORS-MIB until I relaxed the permissions in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` by adding the following:

```
rocommunity public  localhost
```

After restarting snmpd `service snmpd restart` the following commands finally worked:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost .  | grep 2021.13.16.2.1.3.6
> iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.5.25917 = STRING: "2021.13.16.2.1.3.6"

snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost LM-SENSORS-MIB::lmTempSensorsTable
> LM-SENSORS-MIB::lmTempSensorsIndex.7 = INTEGER: 7
> ...
```